# Where should "How do I configure an SSL only site, in a way that doesn't affect browser connection limits" be migrated?

Tags: discussion, support

What SE site is best suited for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621393/how-do-?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are at least two separate questions there. The first one, "how do I properly implement an HTTPS-only site?" belongs on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), in my opinion.

The rest (questions about the effect of certificate choice and server config on performance) would be best served on either [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 2):

Setting up a web server, questions about html/css/js/etc, server SSL certs, etc, etc are not programming or programming related.  In my biased opinion, that belongs on [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)